# Python kernel crashes if I use np.log10 after loading a DLL

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a library to work with Avantes spectrometers in python, here is the library:

```
#as52.py
import ctypes
import time
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('AS5216.dll');
USER_ID_LEN             = 64;
NR_WAVELEN_POL_COEF     = 5;
NR_NONLIN_POL_COEF      = 8;
NR_DEFECTIVE_PIXELS     = 30;
MAX_NR_PIXELS           = 4096;
NR_TEMP_POL_COEF        = 5;
MAX_TEMP_SENSORS        = 3;
ROOT_NAME_LEN           = 6;
AVS_SERIAL_LEN          = 10;
MAX_PIXEL_VALUE         = 0xFFFC;
MAX_VIDEO_CHANNELS      = 2;
MAX_LASER_WIDTH         = 0xFFFF;
HW_TRIGGER_MODE         = 1;
SW_TRIGGER_MODE         = 0;
EDGE_TRIGGER_SOURCE     = 0;
LEVEL_TRIGGER_SOURCE    = 1;
MAX_TRIGGER_MODE        = 1;
MAX_TRIGGER_SOURCE      = 1;
MAX_TRIGGER_SOURCE_TYPE = 1;
MAX_INTEGRATION_TIME    = 600000;    # 600 seconds
SAT_DISABLE_DET         = 0;
SAT_ENABLE_DET          = 1;
SAT_PEAK_INVERSION      = 2;
NR_DAC_POL_COEF         = 2;

class AvsIdentityType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("SerialNumber", ctypes.c_char * AVS_SERIAL_LEN),
                 ("UserFriendlyName", ctypes.c_char * USER_ID_LEN),
                 ("Status", ctypes.c_ubyte)]

class ControlSettingsType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_StrobeControl", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_LaserDelay", ctypes.c_uint),
                 ("m_LaserWidth", ctypes.c_uint),
                 ("m_LaserWaveLength", ctypes.c_float),
                 ("m_StoreToRam", ctypes.c_ushort)]
class DarkCorrectionType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Enable", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_ForgetPercentage", ctypes.c_ubyte)]
class DetectorType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_SensorType", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_NrPixels", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_aFit", ctypes.c_float * NR_WAVELEN_POL_COEF),
                 ("m_NLEnable", ctypes.c_bool),
                 ("m_aNLCorrect", ctypes.c_double * NR_NONLIN_POL_COEF),
                 ("m_aLowNLCounts", ctypes.c_double),
                 ("m_aHighNLCounts", ctypes.c_double),
                 ("m_Gain", ctypes.c_float * MAX_VIDEO_CHANNELS),
                 ("m_Reserved", ctypes.c_float),
                 ("m_Offset", ctypes.c_float * MAX_VIDEO_CHANNELS),
                 ("m_ExtOffset", ctypes.c_float),                 
                 ("m_DefectivePixels", ctypes.c_ushort * NR_DEFECTIVE_PIXELS)]
class SmoothingType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_SmoothPix", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_SmoothModel", ctypes.c_ubyte)]
class SpectrumCalibrationType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Smoothing", SmoothingType),
                 ("m_CalInttime", ctypes.c_float),
                 ("m_aCalibConvers", ctypes.c_float * MAX_NR_PIXELS)]
class IrradianceType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_IntensityCalib", SpectrumCalibrationType),
                 ("m_CalibrationType", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_FiberDiameter", ctypes.c_uint)]
class TriggerType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Mode", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_Source", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_SourceType", ctypes.c_ubyte)]
class MeasConfigType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_StartPixel", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_StopPixel", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_IntegrationTime", ctypes.c_float),
                 ("m_IntegrationDelay", ctypes.c_uint),
                 ("m_NrAverages", ctypes.c_uint),
                 ("m_CorDynDark", DarkCorrectionType),
                 ("m_Smoothing", SmoothingType),
                 ("m_SaturationDetection", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_Trigger", TriggerType),               
                 ("m_Control", ControlSettingsType)]
class TimeStampType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Date", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_Time", ctypes.c_ushort)]
class SDCardType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Enable", ctypes.c_bool),
                 ("m_SpectrumType", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                 ("m_aFileRootName", ctypes.c_byte * ROOT_NAME_LEN),
                 ("m_TimeStamp", TimeStampType)]
class SpectrumCorrectionType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_aSpectrumCorrect", ctypes.c_float * MAX_NR_PIXELS)]
class StandAloneType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Enable", ctypes.c_bool),
                 ("m_Meas", MeasConfigType),
                 ("m_Nmsr", ctypes.c_short),
                 ("m_SDCard", SDCardType)]
class TempSensorType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_aFit", ctypes.c_float * NR_TEMP_POL_COEF)]
class TecControlType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Enable", ctypes.c_bool),
                 ("m_Setpoint", ctypes.c_float),
                 ("m_aFit", ctypes.c_float * NR_DAC_POL_COEF)]
class ProcessControlType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("AnalogLow", ctypes.c_float * 2),
                 ("AnalogHigh", ctypes.c_float * 2),
                 ("DigitalLow", ctypes.c_float * 10),
                 ("DigitalHigh", ctypes.c_float * 10)]
SETTINGS_RESERVED_LEN = ((62*1024) - ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_uint) -
(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_ushort) +   # m_Len
ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_ushort) +  # m_ConfigVersion
USER_ID_LEN +
ctypes.sizeof(DetectorType) +
ctypes.sizeof(IrradianceType) +
ctypes.sizeof(SpectrumCalibrationType) +
ctypes.sizeof(SpectrumCorrectionType) +
ctypes.sizeof(StandAloneType) +
(ctypes.sizeof(TempSensorType)*MAX_TEMP_SENSORS) +
ctypes.sizeof(TecControlType) +
ctypes.sizeof(ProcessControlType)))
class DeviceConfigType(ctypes.Structure):
     _pack_ = 1
     _fields_ = [("m_Len", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_ConfigVersion", ctypes.c_ushort),
                 ("m_aUserFriendlyId", ctypes.c_byte * USER_ID_LEN),
                 ("m_Detector", DetectorType),
                 ("m_Irradiance", IrradianceType),
                 ("m_Reflectance", SpectrumCalibrationType),
                 ("m_SpectrumCorrect", SpectrumCorrectionType),
                 ("m_StandAlone", StandAloneType),
                 ("m_aTemperature", TempSensorType * MAX_TEMP_SENSORS),
                 ("m_TecControl", TecControlType),
                 ("m_ProcessControl", ProcessControlType),                 
                 ("m_aReserved", ctypes.c_ubyte * SETTINGS_RESERVED_LEN)]

AVS_Init = lib['AVS_Init']
AVS_Init.restype = ctypes.c_int

AVS_GetNrOfDevices = lib['AVS_GetNrOfDevices']
AVS_GetNrOfDevices.restype = ctypes.c_int

AVS_GetList = lib['AVS_GetList']
AVS_GetList.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_GetList.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint),ctypes.POINTER(AvsIdentityType)]

AVS_Activate = lib['AVS_Activate']
AVS_Activate.restype = ctypes.c_long
AVS_Activate.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(AvsIdentityType)]

AVS_GetNumPixels = lib['AVS_GetNumPixels'] 
AVS_GetNumPixels.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_GetNumPixels.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ushort)]

AVS_UseHighResAdc = lib['AVS_UseHighResAdc'] 
AVS_UseHighResAdc.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_UseHighResAdc.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_bool]

AVS_GetLambda = lib['AVS_GetLambda'] 
AVS_GetLambda.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_GetLambda.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]

AVS_PollScan = lib['AVS_PollScan'] 
AVS_PollScan.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_PollScan.argtype = ctypes.c_long

#l_PrepareMeasData = MeasConfigType()
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_StartPixel = 0
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_StopPixel = numpix.value - 1           
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_IntegrationTime = 500                  
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_IntegrationDelay = 0;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_NrAverages = 1;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_CorDynDark.m_Enable = 0;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_CorDynDark.m_ForgetPercentage = 100; #0 %          
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Smoothing.m_SmoothPix = 2;             
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Smoothing.m_SmoothModel = 0;               
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_SaturationDetection = 1;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Trigger.m_Mode = 0;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Trigger.m_Source = 0;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Trigger.m_SourceType = 0;
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Control.m_StrobeControl = 0;           
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Control.m_LaserDelay = 0;                  
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Control.m_LaserWidth = 0;          
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Control.m_LaserWaveLength = 0;             
#l_PrepareMeasData.m_Control.m_StoreToRam = 0;
#
AVS_PrepareMeasure = lib['AVS_PrepareMeasure']
AVS_PrepareMeasure.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_PrepareMeasure.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long,ctypes.POINTER(MeasConfigType)]

AVS_Measure = lib['AVS_Measure'] 
AVS_Measure.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_Measure.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_short]

AVS_GetScopeData = lib['AVS_GetScopeData'] 
AVS_GetScopeData.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_GetScopeData.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]

AVS_GetSaturatedPixels = lib['AVS_GetSaturatedPixels'] 
AVS_GetSaturatedPixels.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_GetSaturatedPixels.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)]

AVS_StopMeasure = lib['AVS_StopMeasure']
AVS_StopMeasure.restype = ctypes.c_int
AVS_StopMeasure.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long]

AVS_Deactivate = lib['AVS_Deactivate']
AVS_Deactivate.restype = ctypes.c_bool
AVS_Deactivate.argtypes = [ctypes.c_long]
```

Now if I run something like:

```
from as52 import *
import numpy as np
np.log10(np.arange(1,100))
```

everything is fine, but now if I try:

```
np.log10(np.arange(0,100))
```

the python kernel dies
also something like:

```
np.log10(0)
```

results in a crash ("It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console").
I think it has something to do with the `inf` in python but I do not know how to solve it.
In case you want to try it out, here is a link to 
[AS5216.dll](https://ufile.io/fd0xx) .
I'm using python(x,y) 2.7.10 with spyder 2.3.5 (32bit) on windows 10.

EDIT1:
minimal crash reproducer :

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('AS5216.dll');
import numpy as np
print np.log10(0)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the C code that might cause the problem? I think it will help a lot more than the dll itself

Comment: You should remove a few lines of your source code at a time until you have a minimal reproducer for the problem.

Comment: Also, "results in a crash" is not good enough.  Tell us the full, complete error message and traceback.

Comment: @SashaTsukanov This DLL comes on a DVD with the spectrometer, unfortunately I don't have access to the source code. I wish I could provide a more reliable source for you to download this DLL, I googled "AS5216.dll" and this came up [link](http://www.content.mphotonics.de/AVA/DLL/32bit/)

Comment: @JohnZwinck please see edit1 for a minimal version. Crash in my python looks like this :  "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console". After I restart the kernel %tb does not provide anything useful

Comment: What if you run the program in regular Python instead of IPython Notebook or whatever you're using now?

Comment: @JohnZwinck It doesn't crash, but nothing happens, it doesn't return anything; even if I try to capture the error message with ` try except`

Comment: You could try & attach a debugger. Do you have visual studio?

Comment: @deets Yes I have it. Do you mean that I run the python code in VS ?

Comment: The way you phrase it - no. VS doesn’t speak python. But you can put a long sleep at the beginning of your code (preferably before any other import than time) and thenattach the debugger to the python process. Then when it crashes, you get a thread frame that might give a clue to where they Problem is. In C!